Balance value of three input fields to always sum up to 100
I would like to balance a user input of three input fields so that they will always sum up 100.
The initial state is: 100, 0, 0, when the user enters let's say 50 in the second input, it should become: 50, 50, 0. I am doing this in Vue but technically it is irrelevant for the question. I have tried:
adjustPercentage(changedValue) {
  if (changedValue === 'input1') {
    this.input2 = 100 - this.input1 - this.input3;
    this.input3 = 100 - this.input1 - this.input2;
  } else if (changedValue === 'input2') {
    this.input1 = 100 - this.input2 - this.input3;
    this.input3 = 100 - this.input1 - this.input2;
  } else if (changedValue === 'input3') {
    this.input1 = 100 - this.input2 - this.input3;
    this.input2 = 100 - this.input1 - this.input3;
  }

  // Ensure the values are clamped to avoid negative percentages
  if (this.input1 < 0) this.input1 = 0;
  if (this.input2 < 0) this.input2 = 0;
  if (this.input3 < 0) this.input3 = 0;
},

But I cannot get it to work properly, if I enter let's say a value in input 3 it is exceeding the total sum of 100.

It may be caused by calculating the value of input2 after calculating the value for input1 while using the previous value of input2 There's a mutual dependency between them. What is the exact use case for it? There may be another way of calculating it

Could you include a [mre]?

@HarunYilmaz the use case is that I wanna balance weights of percentages between 3 inputs. Each accounting for a particular value that the user can edit.

You need to move the "clamping" to between the two calculations.,   when in2 changes, so recalc1 based on (100-in2-in3) then, with no other changes, recalc3/in3 is by definition a no change (as the value in in1 is based on the value of in3).  in3 will only change if in1 is not the result of the calculation - ie has been "clamped" - example: 50 0 50 - change in2 to 70 -> 50 75 50 -> in1=(100-75-50) -> -25 75 50 -> limit in1 -> 0 75 50 -> 0 75 25

Also, what is token0 and token1? Shouldnt you change inputX ?

@0stone0 sorry, that was a typo but unrelated to the problem.

@fdomn-m this doesn't work either or I am misunderstanding your comment, can you post an answer kindly?

Ah oke, thanks for fixing, Still don't understand what's going wrong tho.

@0stone0 let's say I go to input2, I enter 25 then it will be 75, 25, 0 (which is correct), when I then go to input3 and enter 100 for example, I will have 0, 25, 100 instead of 0, 0, 100

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbu8d56o/

Ahh like so, well thats explainerd by @fdomn-m's message

What if you have 50, 30, 20 and the initial 50 is changed to zero.  0, 60, 40?  0, 80, 20?

Updated fiddle for your 2nd scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbu8d56o/1/

@James 50,30,20 change to 0 should "balance" to 0, 55, 45?   OPs code would make it 0, 80, 20

Adjusting < 0 to 0 after you're calculating the other fields will cause the calulation to fail.
You'll need to set < 0 to 0 before the next input calculation.

Here an example with a helper function that we call after each line of your existing logics, this could ofc be improved.


const input1 = document.querySelector('input[name=input1]');
const input2 = document.querySelector('input[name=input2]');
const input3 = document.querySelector('input[name=input3]');

const noBelowZero = (input) => (input.value < 0) ? input.value = 0 : {};

const adjust = (event) => {

    let name = event.target.name;

    if (name === 'input1') {
      input2.value = 100 - input1.value - input3.value; noBelowZero(input2);
      input3.value = 100 - input1.value - input2.value; noBelowZero(input3)
    } else if (name === 'input2') {
      input1.value = 100 - input2.value - input3.value; noBelowZero(input1)
      input3.value = 100 - input1.value - input2.value; noBelowZero(input3)
    } else if (name === 'input3') {
      input1.value = 100 - input2.value - input3.value; noBelowZero(input1)
      input2.value = 100 - input1.value - input3.value; noBelowZero(input2)
    }
}

[ input1, input2, input3 ].forEach(i => i.addEventListener('change', adjust));
<input name='input1' value=100 />
<input name='input2' value=0 />
<input name='input3' value=0 />




seems like you got it, thank you! Will do one more test and then accept.

I enter 5 in the second, and 2.7 in the third, I get weird rounding issues, Do you know a simple solution to that?

That's caused by the floating point. You can just round it.
